# how to append .doc files to a template .doc file using c#

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-interop

In my application i am creating many .doc files and i want to append it to make a single .doc file . how could i do this using C#

Answer (score 0):

Since your application already writes some doc files, I will assume you have experience with office interop.

A simple approach would be:

- open the target file
- for each source file:

  - open it
  - select all its content
  - copy the content in the clipboard
  - paste into the target file
  - close the source file
- close the target file.

Comment: Thas is fine when we have text only but what if  source file contain images also?

Answer (score 0):

If you are already using Office Interop, then just use the InsertFile method of the Range or Selection objects to insert the other documents.